# Add class/style to active button in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

*This isn't tied to the router menu.*

I have a Price sheet witch consists of 3 sub-sheets.

Above the single visible sheet is are 3 buttons which, when clicked, show the corresponding sheet.

[The design of the pricesheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lc9J.png)

I was lookin at the Vue style bindings but they only trigger on `True / False` and not on the value of the single variable.

Of course there's the option to have a data() variable for each button and upon change set the other two to false, but maybe there's a way to bring that repeated code to a single variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't work only on true and false.

For example:

My data indicated that the 1st button is active:

```js
data() {
    return {
        activeBtn: 1,
    };
},
```

To bind the style to the active button, just set the style attribute to an if shorthand which checks the value of the data and changes the string-typed style.

```html
<div class="btn1" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: activeBtn == 1 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></div>
<div class="btn2" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: activeBtn == 2 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></div>
<div class="btn3" v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: activeBtn == 3 ? 'red' : 'green' }"></div>
```

[Screenshot with the styling like in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8i4G.png)

*Of course it's better to not specify the styling but the class (for multiple style values)*